# Using Jedis from connection pool for PubSub

Tags: redis, jedis

As Jedis [documentation](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started#user-content-using-jedis-in-a-multithreaded-environment) state that Jedis client is not thread-safe.

> A single Jedis instance is not threadsafe!

So I am using JedisPool. I want to push data to browser's WebSocket client from server. For this I am using Redis's PubSub mechanism.

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/{channelName}", configurator = GetHttpSessionConfigurator.class)
public class WSEndpoint {

private WSJedisPubSub wsJedisPubSub;
private static JedisPool jedisPool = null;

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session,
        @PathParam("channelName") String channelName) throws IOException,
        EncodeException {
    // FIXME proper synchronization is required here
    if (jedisPool == null) {
        initPool();
    }
    wsJedisPubSub = new WSJedisPubSub(session);
    try (Jedis redisClient = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        redisClient.subscribe(wsJedisPubSub, channelName);
    }

    private void initPool() {
        JedisPoolConfig jedisConfiguration = new JedisPoolConfig();
        jedisPool = new JedisPool(jedisConfiguration, "localhost", 6379);
    }
}
```

[full code](https://gist.github.com/thebhushanp/9b3dc3129064565c7f4203918ee939ac)

My application can have thousands of websockets connected to it. I have doubts about following piece of code.

```
    try (Jedis redisClient = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        redisClient.subscribe(wsJedisPubSub, channelName);
    }
```

1. This redisClient should get close after try-with-resouce block, but still it is working(getting subscribed events). How ?
2. By default, pool size is 8. I can set to n but eventually I will have n+1 web sockets. What is the best way to deal with this ? Should I have only one Jedis instance and do the routing of message by myself ?
3. If Jedis client gets disconnected, then what is the recommended way for reconnect here ?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have exactly the same questions :)

Comment: I implemented it by having only one Jedis instance n doing routing myself.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing the same